# How to post issues to gitlab using python?

Tags: python, gitlab

I have two repositories(for same project) one in github and another one in gitlab.I am extracting issues from github in json format. Now I want to post all these issues to gitlab repo. I am not getting any error but issues are not being posted to gitlab

```
import requests
import getpass

GITHUB_USER = raw_input("Enter github Username: ")
GITHUB_PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("Enter github Password: ")
REPO = raw_input("Enter Repository name: ")
STATE = raw_input("Enter State(all,open,closed): ")
Assignee = raw_input("Enter assignee name: ")
GITHUB_URL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/issues?state=%s' % (REPO, STATE)
AUTH = (GITHUB_USER, GITHUB_PASSWORD)
github_issues = requests.get(GITHUB_URL , auth=AUTH)

GITLAB_URL = 'https://gitlab.com'
GITLAB_TOKEN = 'xxxx'
GITLAB_PROJECT = 'my_project'
GITLAB_USER = raw_input("Enter gitlab Username: ") 
GITLAB_PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("Enter gitlab Password: ") 
AUTH = (GITLAB_USER, GITLAB_PASSWORD)
for issue in github_issues.json():

    gl_issue = requests.post(
        GITLAB_URL + '/myproject/issues',
        headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': GITLAB_TOKEN},
        auth=AUTH,
        data={
            'title': issue['title'],
            'description': issue['body']
        }
    )
```

Comment: I have just hidden my project name this is the full code which i tried to post to gitlab

Comment: try to print the content of `gl_issue` in every iteration. The fact that `requests.post` doesn't raise an exception doesn't mean there are no errors explained in the response.

Comment: I am getting <Response [422]>

Comment: So you *are* getting an error. You probably have a syntax error in your request, you'll need to search in the gitlab API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for issue in github_issues.json():
    url='https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/%s/issues?title=%s&description=%s' %(PROJECT_ID,issue['title'],issue['body'])
    response = requests.post(url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "xxxxxxxx"})
```

Comment: although is a good and right answer, a bit of explanation would be good. And correct the last line ..requests.post(url, headers=){"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "xxxxxxxx"} to requests.post(url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "xxxxxxxx"})

Comment: Answer is corrected, request & response docs is available at official gitlab API documentation.